# How to filter max value records in SQL query

Tags: sql

I want to get all records except max value records. Could you pls suggest query for that.

For eg,(Im taking AVG field to filter)

```
SNO   Name     AVG
1     AAA       85
2     BBB       90
3     CCC       75
```

The query needs to return only 1st and 3rd records.

Comment: did you tried with `NOT IN` ??

Comment: -1 You have not shown what you've tried. Your problem is quite trivial.

Comment: I have tried but in java code.

Comment: @Srinivasan Code that you should show in question should be related to the question. Like this we know that you tried to do yourself and we are not doing your job. Also it's helpful for better understanding og problem. Anyway, I'd create stored procedure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17c2a6/28

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below query:

```
select * from tab where avg<(select max(avg) from tab);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a ranking function like `DENSE_RANK`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SNO, Name, AVG,
       RN = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

(if you are using SQL-Server >= 2005)

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2762b/1/0)

Comment: Not all DBMSs support CTEs.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Sample where avg not in (select max(avg) from sample);
```

I think this should do

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SELECT SNO, Name, AVG 
    FROM TableName 
    WHERE AVG NOT IN (SELECT  MAX(AVG) 
                      FROM TableName )
```

Comment: Why `not in` instead of `<`?

Comment: I just point out one more method. Also more general, it is working fine even if it is `MAX()`, `MIN()` or `AVG()`.